# php filemtime returning false other then the php application's root directory

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am developing a php application using Ubuntu 11.10 in development environment.
I have a directory '/usr/src/app_name/' which contains some pdf files.
I need to retrieve the file names along with their last modification time.

The following is the code snippet:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/usr/src/app_name') as $file) {
    if($file->isDot()) continue;
      print $file->getFilename().' : '.date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file)).'<br>';
}
```

I get the file names correctly but gives me:  PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed.... and I get the time as 1 January, 1970.

But, if I change the directory to application root directory i.e.

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/var/www/app_name') as $file) {
  if($file->isDot()) continue;
    print $file->getFilename().' : '.date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file)).'<br>';
 }
```

I get all the names of the php files of the app along with their last modification time.

Any help on this will much appreciated....Thanks in advance.

Comment: `open_basedir` is restrictive?

Comment: Did you try `filemtime($file->getRealPath())`?

Comment: shurely it is access privileges issue

Comment: It's either safe mode, open_basedir, or the directory doesn't have the correct access permissions/ownership

Comment: Thanks all of you for your comments...filemtime($file->getRealPath()) worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know I already said that in a comment, but at the time I could not know if it was the issue or not. So here is the full explanation.

Using `filemtime($file->getRealPath())` could help solve the issue since [a comment on the doc of filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.filemtime.php#95955) mentions that you need to feed **absolute paths** to `filemtime`. Now using the result of the iterator directly (your `$file` variable) is probably going to call [`DirectoryIterator::__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.tostring.php) which only returns the name of the file, and not the absolute path.

It could have worked for `/var/www` because it was the working directory, but I can't be sure.